# RabbitMQ cross data center messaging over unreliable network

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, messaging

Server A and B are in 2 different physical locations - There is an instance of RabbitMQ in each location. The network that connects the locations is terrible and totally unreliable. The specific requirements of the application is that messages placed on Server A queues are mirrored on Server B and vice versa.

The unreliable network seems to be wreaking havoc in terms of the reliablity of message delivery - the shovel plugin is what I am using at the moment but it appears to be dropping messages on the odd occasion. I can only assume that the message is being acked from the source queue before being properly delivered to the destination queue but there is nothing in the logs to suggest this is what is happening

Is there a better way to achieve this queue mirroring over an unreliable network like this? I have considered dropping the queue entirely and instead moving to a more synchronous approach (an http api maybe) but I'd prefer not to do that without understanding if there is a better way to achieve a mirrored queue across a flaky network connection or how I can more accurately determine what the issue is.

Comment: I'm surprised to hear the shovel plugin is dropping messages, alternatively you could look at the Federation plugin: http://www.rabbitmq.com/federation.html

Comment: shovel config would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Shovel is designed with failure in mind. Make sure `ack_mode` for the shovel config is set to `on_confirm`. This way messages wont disappear from the source broker until fully confirmed as delivered to the destination broker. See [ref](http://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html)